# Why is my implementation of AwsSignatureVersion4 responding with a Forbidden status

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-signature

I am making use of the .Net `AwsSignatureVersion4` package to facilitate the signing of the AWS request.

Part of the process is to first assume an IAM role, and use the credentials received from the AWS.SDK STS service (`AccessKeyId`, `SecretAccessKey` and `SessionToken`) as parameters to the overloaded `HttpClient.PostAsync` method.  I am however unable to get a successful response, all the requests responds with Forbidden.

The steps I follow to perform the request are as follows:

1. Assume Role via AWS.SDK
2. Use the credentials retrieved from step 1 as input parameters to HttpClient.PostAsync.

In addition to the credentials parameter, an endpoint, a null instance of HttpContent (because there is no post body), aws region and -service name are provided:

`HttpClient.PostAsync("api gateway endpoint", null, "aws region", "execute-api", credentials)`

Performing these steps and executing the Post responds with a Forbidden status.

Any guidance on where I might be going wrong please?

Comment: Are the credentials *actually* valid for that endpoint? Have you performed an `sts` `get-caller-identity` call with those credentials to confirm the credentials are valid and for the role you expect?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that the credentials are valid. Performing the request via Postman (after obtaining the temp credentials) does respond with a success.